# Animate CSS on selection of <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to trigger a change of CSS for some objects further down in my code when one of the option tags is selected. I did not include them here as they are not pertinent to the issue at hand which is the jQuery. I am at a loss at this point. Here is what I have so far...is it even possible?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#feed-filter option:selected").change(function () {
        $("#CA, #GA, #GD").animate({height: '0px'});
    })
})
</script>

<div class="feed-filter">
    <select id="feed-filter" name="feed-filter">
        <option id="option-ALL" value="ALL" selected>ALL</option>
        <option id="option-CA" value="A">A</option>
        <option id="option-DAD" value="B">B</option>
        <option id="option-GA" value="C">C</option>
        <option id="option-GD" value="D">D</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: An option that is selected doesn't really change does it, the select does ?

Comment: I don't see any of the following elements in the HTML provided (`#CA, #GA, #GD`)

Comment: Those are referencing some objects further down in my code that I want to alter the height of.

Comment: try $('#feed-filter').on('change', handler);

Comment: assuming CA, GA and GD are blank divs. please check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7audaoLd/ . if you intend to hide these div's then you can use the slideUp or fadeOut functions

Comment: Okay, now that helped a bit. The only thing that is wrong is that I need to be able to append this function to each of the options so that they can do different things...as apposed to all triggering the same function. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to attach the function to each of the options? if you're going to check for values, you can simply get it from $('#feed-filter').val() in the change event

Comment: @Sushil I actually figured it out by using:
$("#option-DAD").is(':selected') && $("#CA, #GA, #GD").animate({height: '0px'});

Comment: how are you doing it now?

Answer (score 0):

firstly you aren't triggering a CSS animation, that is a jQuery animation. Secondly, the ID's you are animating don't exist in the HTML, and thirdly, your selector/listener is invalid, you need to listen to `$('select').change();`

If you need to then access the value of the selected option you can do so by doing something like this

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I did not address the ID's located in the jQuery. I have now addressed them.